# Expectation value of a time evolved circuit in the non-Z basis

Tags: measurement, simulation, hamiltonian-simulation

I am new to qiskit and have hit a roadblock in my calculation. Given the following circuit:

```
q = QuantumRegister(3)

qc = QuantumCircuit(q)
t = Parameter('t')

#set up initial state
#qc.h(0)

#unitary decomposition
qc.ry(np.pi/2,1)
qc.ry(np.pi/2,2)

qc.cnot(1,2)
qc.crz( 2*t, q[0],q[2])
qc.cnot(1,2)
qc.ry(-np.pi/2,1)
qc.ry(-np.pi/2,2)

#qc.measure(0,0)
```

[image: QC Draw]

I want to be able to define an initial state, e.g. $|\phi\rangle=|+\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle$, where $|\psi\rangle=|00...0\rangle$, time evolve, and then measure the expectation value of the top qubit register in the $\langle2\sigma_{+}^{0}\rangle=\langle\sigma_{x}^{0}\rangle+i\langle\sigma_{y}^{0}\rangle$ basis. Where superscript 0 defines the register. More mathematically, define the entire circuit above as $U(t)$. Then, $|\phi(t)\rangle=U(t)|\phi\rangle$, giving, $\langle2\sigma_{+}^{0}\rangle=\langle \phi(t)| (\sigma_{x}^{0}+i\sigma_{y}^{0})|\phi(t)\rangle$.

Additionally, $t_{final}=n*dt$, meaning, a grid of time values with time spacing dt, and n total grid points will be created. Therefore, $n$ total circuits will be constructed, corresponding to n total expectation values.

Things to consider here...

- This type of problem, but more involved, will need to be ran on the QC
- I more or less understand how to time evolve a circuit using bind parameters

I don't need the answer, just a push in the right direction since I am still so new to qiskit. I don't really know what my options are to solve such a problem. To give context, the end goal of acquiring the expectation value at given points in time due to a small time evolution $U(j*dt)$  to construct time series data $F(t)=\langle2\sigma_{+}^{0}(t)\rangle$.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at qiskit's Estimator?

Comment: I have not, I will check that out!